# How to delete objects from two apps with the same model name?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two apps `news` and `article` which both have exactly the same model name `Comment`:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Now, in a view I want to delete certain comments from both apps:

```
Comment.objects.filter(author=someauthor).delete()
```

How can I achieve that without changing the model names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `import ... as ...` so that both model names do not conflict:

```
from news.models import Comment as NewsComment
from article.models import Comment as ArticleComment

...

NewsComment.objects.filter(author=someauthor).delete()
ArticleComment.objects.filter(author=someauthor).delete()
```